# Autodesk Forge Viewer Toolbar Icon frequently shows random characters

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are using forge viewer for our application. Sometimes the dropdown button icon show random characters instead of a dropdown arrow. This happens once in a few sessions.

[image]

What could be the reason? Is there any way to fix this?

Edit 1: 
I was checking the Styles and this particular arrow is  -

```
.adsk-button-arrow > .adsk-button-icon::before {
content: "▴";
padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

http://graphemica.com/%E2%96%B4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your browser has hard time identifying the proper text encoding.

Some browsers, like Safari, have the options to play with text encoding, so you could try selecting "Unicode".
Other browsers, like Chrome, removed that option, relying totally on "autodetect".

To "force" your browser to use the expected Unicode, in the ***head*** section of your ***html*** page add the charset meta:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

It should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this. Since this issue is not consistent, I can confirm the fix only after running the application for some time.